# Is there different between "Color Scheme" and "Color Palette"?

Tags: css, colors, naming-conventions, naming

Is there different between color scheme and color palette?

in one of my projects (a web template), it provided some options for customers to customize, there are two color related options make me a bit of confusing with naming convention.

**Option 1 Choices:**

- Light
- Dark

this option will change background color, but not only background.

**Option 2 choices:**

- Fresh
- Ocean
- Classic
- Custom

this option will change primary color accent color etc.

seems the term `color palettes` is semantic for option 2, but I doubt that is `color scheme` good for option 1? maybe `color theming` or `color version` or any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a "different" between "Color Scheme" and "Color Palette": although "palette" is now used rather frequently to mean "color scheme" it also refers to a specific technical thing; that thing is used rarely now, but still the term could easily confuse some people.
"Color scheme" can hardly mean anything else, so I would use that for the option 2.

For the option 1 it's hard to find a single term that can describe it; not knowing how to call it someone even got to name it "value".
The most commonly used term is probably "lightness" (I'm not really an expert though).

In the user interface (if there is one) I would either simply put the two terms as two alternative options (e.g. "light mode" and "dark mode") or as shipshape said make the option a boolean named "dark mode".
In your source code you can admit some not-so-clear term, so you might choose to use an enumeration variable named e.g. "InterfaceLigthness"; or you can simply use a boolean "DarkMode".

Answer (score 0):

"Color Palettes" is fine for the second options.

The first option works more like a switch, since there are only two states. If the "Light" option is the default, you could call the switch "Dark Mode". For example, [MetaFilter](https://www.metafilter.com/) has this option.